# Provide an implementation to a typed factory's method

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a typed factory interface as follows:

```
public interface ILogMessageFactory
{
    ILogMessage Create(LogMessageType logMessageType, String text);
}
```

and I am registering it all follows:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

    container.Register(
        Component.For(typeof(ConsolePrompter)),
        Component.For<ILogger>().ImplementedBy<ConsoleLogger>().LifeStyle.Transient,
        Component.For<ILogMessageFactory>().AsFactory(),
        Component.For<ILogMessage>().ImplementedBy<LogMessage>().LifeStyle.Transient
        );
}
```

The problem is that I want to implement the `ILogMessageFactory.Create` method myself, to set a few things before I return.

I've tried the obvious naïve solution without any success:

```
 Component.For<ILogMessageFactory>().ImplementedBy<LogMessageFactory>().AsFactory()
```

Am I approaching this wrong? Should I just keep all initialization in the constructor of the given object?

Comment: What sort of thing do you want to initialize?

Comment: Right now, probably nothing that couldn't be done in a constructor (Like a time-code on the log messages). Although I'm worried that I'll find something that needs to be done before the creation itself, though. What about choosing which object to create through the factory? Do I then create a factory of factories or would implementing the Create() function be a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector` if this is something that really belongs to the factory. Alternatively use `.OnCreate()` on the component the factory resolves